# Puppet agent on Windows unless doesn't work how I think?

Tags: windows, puppet

Ok, I've spent days chasing this around. Is there an issue with puppet agent 3.7.1 x64 on Windows 7 x64 where execs with "unless" don't ever NOT run the command? I've tried doing Batch example:

> unless  => "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe source list | findstr -i 'chocolatey [Disabled]'",

Powershell and now a compiled AutoIT executable:

```
exec { 'disablepublicchocolatey':
        command => "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe source disable -n=chocolatey",
        unless  => 'c:/ProgramData/puppetfiles/checkifexists.exe repo "chocolatey [disabled]"',
        require => [Exec['chocolatelyinstall'],File['checkifexists.exe']],
      }
```

My script returns 1 if it finds the text 'chocolatey [disabled]' in the output of choco source list (the text match is NOT case sensitive)... So... this should NOT run if

```
c:\TEMP\AutoitScripts\chocolatey>choco source list     
Chocolatey v0.9.9.6   
chocolatey [Disabled] - https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/
```

but it seem to always run... Is there a bug? Am I just very confused?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you always trying to run the command or do you want it to run whenever puppet is run?

Comment: What I want to do is NOT run the command if "chocolatey [Disabled]" is in the output of choco source list.

Comment: have you tried only if?  onlyif  => 'c:/ProgramData/puppetfiles/checkifexists.exe repo "chocolatey [enabled]"'

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400186/how-do-i-get-puppet-exec-resource-to-determine-if-a-chocolatey-source-has-alread/30440506?noredirect=1#comment49056144_30440506

Answer (score 2):

To use commands with pipe `|`, you must use the [shell builtins](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/resources_exec_windows.html#shell-builtins) work around with cmd.exe /C:

See the example below:

```
exec { 'configure_timezone':
  command => "tzutil.exe /s \"${timezone}\"",
  unless  => "cmd.exe /C tzutil.exe /g | findstr /C:\"${timezone}\"",
}
```

Comment: Well, I ended up not needing to do this as I found a config file I could just manage as a template, which "just works".

Comment: @jmp242 awesome :)